# iCloud Contacts web interface on Windows - How to copy an address?

Tags: icloud, contacts, copy-paste

I maintain my contact list on an iPad/iPhone and use iCloud's web interface on my desktop PC.

I cannot find any way to copy any data that is also a link, such as a person's address or email, from the iCloud web interface.  The usual Alt-hilight to bypass link-following does not highlight, and right-clicking does not provide any "copy" option.

Is there a way to highlight and copy information from the iCloud web interface when that information is also a link?

Comment: What about clicking the address and then copying it from Maps ( or whatever it opens). I'll admit I'm not familiar with iCloud's website, but it's an idea. It would also help to know what browser you are using.

Comment: You can export any number of contacts [shift- or ctrl-select for multiples] as .vcf files from the Gear Icon, bottom left of the Contacts window.

Comment: @Tetsujin I realize that, but all I want to do is copy/paste info, like a mailing address, from iCloud to another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation in different browsers I have come to the conclusion that on Firefox, the alt-click-drag action to select link text while suppressing link-follow seems to require finer mouse-cursor placement.  Start just outside the bounding box and nothing gets selected; start too far in and one character doesn't get selected.

But at least you CAN select the text.  It goes into the clipboard with each field followed by a newline, but that's a minor issue.  There really should be a "copy to clipboard" button.